# iptables not starting up

Tags: rhel, iptables, kernel-modules

I have inherited a custom built Linux kernel 2.6.30.9 and am just upgrading the underlying OS from RHEL 5.4 to 5.8 (kernels 2.6.18.164 and 2.6.18.308 respectively).

When booting, the following is displayed:

```
unloading iptables modules                   [  OK  ]
Applying iptables firewall rules: modprobe: FATAL: module ip-tables not found.

iptables-restore v1.3.5: iptables-restore unable to initialize 'filter'

Error occurred at line 3
try 'iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information
.                                             [FAILED]
```

the `/etc/iptables` file looks like:

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-securitylevel
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p 51 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp --dport 5353 -d 224.0.0.251 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

the section of `kernel_config`

```
#
# IP: Netfilter Configuration
#
# CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV4 is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_QUEUE is not set
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ADDRTYPE is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_AH is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ECN is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_TTL is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_LOG is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ULOG is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_TTL is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_RAW is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_SECURITY is not set
# CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPTABLES is not set
# CONFIG_IP_DCCP is not set
# CONFIG_IP_SCTP is not set
# CONFIG_TIPC is not set
# CONFIG_ATM is not set
# CONFIG_BRIDGE is not set
# CONFIG_NET_DSA is not set
# CONFIG_VLAN_8021Q is not set
# CONFIG_DECNET is not set
# CONFIG_LLC2 is not set
# CONFIG_IPX is not set
# CONFIG_ATALK is not set
# CONFIG_X25 is not set
# CONFIG_LAPB is not set
# CONFIG_ECONET is not set
# CONFIG_WAN_ROUTER is not set
# CONFIG_PHONET is not set
CONFIG_NET_SCHED=y
```

and this is matched in `/proc/config.gz`

Is there a simple way to bring this to life? Do iptables behave differently when compiled into the kernel compares to compiled as module objects?

Comment: `iptables` printed  `iptables-restore unable to initialize 'filter'`, it's very strange, because filter is built-in in kernel, So you test step by step from first rule by hand not `iptables-restore`  until last rule,it cause you find rule which has problem.

Comment: It seems that the NF_FILTER is not set, which means it is not built-in, it may have been compiled separately, but if it wasn't, you need to build it either as a module or by rebuilding the kernel.

I would offer to set all netfilter related configurations to module or yes, so you won't have issues like this in the future.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have helped. I switched a lot more modules on in the kernel build so I'm not entirely sure which the crucial one was.